# jQuery doesn't pass in function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, plupload

I'm trying to implement a jQuery function to upload file on a website. The script uses 'plupload'.

Unfortunately there is an other jQuery fonction running on background.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.supersized({
            // Functionality
            slide_interval: ss_interval, // Length between transitions
            transition: 1, // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left or ss_transitionType
            transition_speed: ss_transitionSpeed, // Speed of transition
            // Slides   
            slides: [ // Slideshow Images
            {
                image: 'images/gallery/1.jpg',
                title: 'Upload and share your music with other...',
                title2: 'Music'
            }, {
                image: 'images/gallery/2.jpg',
                title: 'Share your work online and access your documents from anywhere. ',
                title2: 'Documents'
            }, {
                image: 'images/gallery/3.jpg',
                title: 'Show off your favorite photos and videos to the world.',
                title2: 'Photography'
            }, {
                image: 'images/gallery/4.jpg',
                title: 'Let the world watch your videos, or share them privately.',
                title2: 'Video'
            }, {
                image: 'images/gallery/8.jpg',
                title: 'Free file storage service. Share files with your friends.',
                title2: 'Upload and Share'
            }]
        });
        $("#uploader").plupload({
            // General settings
            runtimes: 'flash,html5,browserplus,silverlight,gears,html4',
            url: 'upload.php',
            max_file_size: '1000mb',
            max_file_count: 20, // user can add no more then 20 files at a time
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            unique_names: true,
            multiple_queues: true,
            // Resize images on clientside if we can
            resize: {
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                quality: 90
            },
            // Rename files by clicking on their titles
            rename: true,
            // Sort files
            sortable: true,
            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters: [{
                title: "Image files",
                extensions: "jpg,gif,png"
            }, {
                title: "Zip files",
                extensions: "zip,avi"
            }],
            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: 'js/upload/plupload.flash.swf',
            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url: 'js/upload/plupload.silverlight.xap'
        });
        // Client side form validation
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');
            // Files in queue upload them first
            if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
                // When all files are uploaded submit form
                uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                    if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                        $('form')[0].submit();
                    }
                });
                uploader.start();
            } else alert('You must at least upload one file.');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the problem : nothing work, the page return nothing. But if I delete this part (see below) the upload's fonction works:

```
$.supersized({
    // ...
});
```

Please can someone help me with this? I'm getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pajinate' jScript.js:134
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new d.fn.init(a,b,g)} has no method 'supersized' jquery.min.js:16

Comment: do you get any errors .... check your console ....if yes then post it here...that would be helptful to figure out the problem

Comment: what is `$.supersized`?

Comment: this is a slideshow. See more here : http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html

Comment: Well, the error means that either the file which provides this method was not loaded correctly or that's not the function's name.

Comment: Are you including the files to make the supersized slideshow plugin work?  If files are missing, it would trigger errors like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewing the plugins ..there are two main files related to this plugin `js/supersized.3.2.6.min.js` and `theme/supersized.shutter.min.js`... looks like you are missing one of these files . load it in the `<head>` after jquery.js and it should work..

Comment: the both scripts are loaded in the header, no doubt about that. I thing that the problem is about the both script can't be loaded at the same time or something like that..

Comment: `can't be loaded` i think that should not happen if you are calling it one after another.... view sorce and click the link.. that should show  u the file's content .. just to make sure.. the path that u gave is correct

Comment: I have check. There is no problem. the proof is that if I delete the     supersized  part, the upload plugin works.

Comment: `the proof is that if I delete the supersized part, the upload plugin works` that is why i had a doubt about not loading the  file correctly... seeing your errors `has no method 'supersized' `....which mean it could not find a method called supersized....so how can this be if your loading it correctly rite .. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I have discover where my problem are, thanks to all of you !

The problem was that I had 2 version of jquery loader. I have delete the older version and it works !

Thanks all